# Android - send and receive XML using HTTPPOST

Tags: android, xml, http-post

Hello Fine Minds of SO!

I know that this issue and versions of it have been posed numerous times on SO, and I have read every thread I can find on the issue.  I have tried every combination of solution I can find, but somehow, I am still having issues.  I hope you won't mind me creating my own question so I can post my particular code.  I am completely green on Android apps, and have some basic Java background.

To define some variables...

sendXML is a string that is my XML code.

httppost is the URL that I am posting to.

points is a TextView that I will eventually update based on the server's response XML.

```
    public void postTo() {

    try {
        StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(sendXML,HTTP.UTF_8);
        entity.setContentType("text/xml");
        httppost.setEntity(entity);

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity responseEntity= response.getEntity();
        points.setText(EntityUtils.toString(responseEntity));

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        points.setText("SomeMessageHere");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException q) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        points.setText("SomeMessageHere");
        q.printStackTrace();

    }

}
```

Whenever I try to click the button in my app that calls postTo(), my entire app crashes.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Logcat below:

```
03-14 19:03:13.761: E/AndroidRuntime(922): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-14 19:03:13.761: E/AndroidRuntime(922): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Source     string may not be null
03-14 19:03:13.761: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity.<init>(StringEntity.java:59)
03-14 19:03:13.761: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at  com.appname.app.Stash.postTo(Stash.java:136)
03-14 19:03:13.761: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at com.appname.app.Stash$1.onClick(Stash.java:97)
03-14 19:03:13.761: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
03-14 19:03:13.761: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
03-14 19:03:13.761: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
03-14 19:03:13.761: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-14 19:03:13.761: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-14 19:03:13.761: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
03-14 19:03:13.761: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-14 19:03:13.761: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-14 19:03:13.761: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-14 19:03:13.761: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-14 19:03:13.761: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-14 19:03:13.810: W/ActivityManager(297):   Force finishing activity com.appname.app/.Stash
03-14 19:03:13.860: W/WindowManager(297): Failure taking screenshot for (328x583) to layer 21015
03-14 19:03:14.360: I/Choreographer(297): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-14 19:03:14.390: W/ActivityManager(297): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{411022b8 u0 com.appname.app/.Stash}
03-14 19:03:14.390: E/SurfaceFlinger(36): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
```

Below is an additional logcat printing out the value of the sendXML string.  I have tried both with and without including xml version="1.0" at the beginning of the string.  I am not certain which is correct.  The XMLNS="URLHERE" of course has the correct URL to post to:

```
03-14 23:53:26.870: I/myApp(1048): sendXML = <?xml version="1.0"?><EmailRequest xmlns="URLHERE"><Hash>5e1da0407254ec8882c6f6c27385a890ef544b32</Hash></EmailRequest>
03-14 23:53:26.970: D/AndroidRuntime(1048): Shutting down VM
03-14 23:53:26.970: W/dalvikvm(1048): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
03-14 23:53:26.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1048): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-14 23:53:26.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1048): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
03-14 23:53:26.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1048):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
03-14 23:53:26.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1048):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
03-14 23:53:26.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1048):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
03-14 23:53:26.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1048):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
03-14 23:53:26.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1048):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
03-14 23:53:26.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1048):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
03-14 23:53:26.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1048):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
03-14 23:53:26.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1048):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
03-14 23:53:26.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1048):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
03-14 23:53:26.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1048):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
03-14 23:53:26.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1048):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
03-14 23:53:26.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1048):     at com.myapp.app.Stash.postTo(Stash.java:140)
03-14 23:53:26.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1048):     at com.mymapp.app.Stash$1.onClick(Stash.java:96)
03-14 23:53:26.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1048):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
03-14 23:53:26.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1048):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
03-14 23:53:26.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1048):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
03-14 23:53:26.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1048):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-14 23:53:26.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1048):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-14 23:53:26.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1048):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
03-14 23:53:26.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1048):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-14 23:53:26.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1048):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-14 23:53:26.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1048):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-14 23:53:26.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1048):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-14 23:53:26.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1048):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you copy the error from the logcat and add it here?

Answer (score 0):

Have you asked for internet permissions? If not, add it to the manifest as follows.

```
<manifest xlmns:android...>
  ...
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

EDIT: Ok so the stack trace seems to suggest that your sendXML string is null. Can you add

```
Log.i("myApp", "sendXML = " + sendXML);
```

at the top of the try block to check if this is the case. It will print it to the logcat.

Comment: Thanks, Leeds.  I have asked for internet permissions in the manifest already, although mine is asked at the top of the file.  Is that an issue?  Here is the logcat:

Comment: No that shouldn't be an issue. I've added an edit to my answer, hope that helps.

Comment: It doesn't appear that the sendXML is null.  I will edit myy original post with the updated logcat.  Thanks for all your help.

Comment: When I run the POST through curl, it does take about 30 seconds for the XML response to return.  Could it be that my app thinks the button has crashed because it takes so long?